# Gradle build failing with error: plugin was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04

No changes were made today to code, however gradle build stopped working with following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/data/code/.../build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://repo.spring.io/milestone)
    maven2(https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Try to see if there were any issues with network reaching spring website, with curl showing errors as below

```
curl https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Seems spring website certificate was issued by Digicert on "Tuesday, July 20, 2021 at 5:30:00 AM", Might be CA Certs is missing on my ubuntu 16.04 system.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the spring repo is down https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/repo.spring.io.html This is causing us a huge amount of pain and it is not reported on https://status.spring.io/